# Using Binary Encoding : How to get the original values back from encoded values?

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I have the below data frame:

```
data={'automobile':['car','car','car','car','scooter','scooter','bike','bike','bike']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

encoder=ce.BinaryEncoder(cols=['automobile'])
df=encoder.fit_transform(df)
```

This gives me binary columns which is expected. But while performing clustering analysis how can I get to know which binary value corresponds to which automobile category.

Comment: encoder has a inverse_transform method. have you tried it?

Comment: I read the docs but not exactly able to implement it

Comment: you just need to pass the binary df to the function.how are you trying?

Comment: It says BinaryEncoder object has no attribute inverse_transform

Comment: you are trying encoder.inverse_transform( df ) . right ? seems strange.

Comment: yes exactly. Even I am not able to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you  want to keep Label for 'decoding', i suggest you to use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
data = {'automobile': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'scooter', 'scooter', 'bike', 'bike', 'bike']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ler = LabelEncoder().fit(df['automobile'])
df['automobile']=ler.transform(df['automobile'])

dico = dict(zip(ler.classes_, ler.transform(ler.classes_)))

print(df)
print(dico)
```

output: df

```
   automobile
0           1
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           2
5           2
6           0
7           0
8           0
```

---

output: dico

```
{'bike': 0, 'car': 1, 'scooter': 2}
```

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer